# Design View issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

How can I make my "datalist" control **visible** in **Design View**?

I know it exists, the site runs perfectly and the C# code references it, as well as the asp code, however, I don't find it in Design View. Please advise.

Thank you!
Anna

LATER EDIT (I was suggested to publish the code):

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>



    <table class="style1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                Name:</td>
            <td>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
                    NavigateUrl='<%# MyLinkGen.ToFilm(Eval("fid").ToString()) %>'
                    Text='<%# HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Eval("name").ToString()) %>'></asp:HyperLink>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" 
                    ImageUrl='<%# String.Format("~/img/{0}.jpg",Eval("imgpath1")) %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Directed by:</td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Eval("director").ToString()) %>'></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Actors:</td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Eval("actors").ToString()) %>'></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Rating:</td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Eval("rating").ToString()) %>'></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Description:</td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Eval("descrip").ToString()) %>'></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Price:</td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("price", "{0:c}") %>'></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>


</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Comment: if you post the relevant aspx and html markup I could help a bit more.

Comment: Thank you very much, Jonathan, I edited the question to add the code. Have a nice day. Anna

Comment: So yes, this will not show up in the design view since the data is added at runtime by a DataBind() call and you don't have a datasource hard coded into the markup. There is no way to fix that--it is behaving as it should. B.T.W. I am assuming that visual studio generated this code since you are using tables. This code will probably not work across multiple browsers. I suggest spending some time just learning modern CSS and html techniques.

Comment: Thank you, Jonathan! So I was chasing rainbows! It's good to know _that_ is in fact normal behavour, so I can go and focus on other areas of my website now; Granted, I will take your suggestions into account about CSS! Regards, Anna.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the visibility of every panel, div, or table all of the way down until you get to your datalist. Also, check that the display attribute is not set to "none" for any of the containers. The other thing to look at is when the datarows are bound to the datalist. If you don't have a static datasource set, then the datalist will not show up in the design view, since the data is bound at runtime in the page load.

Visual Studio's design view is finicky at best, and generates very poor quality html, CSS, and aspx markup. It really is in the best interest of everyone to just quit using it altogether  and learn html and CSS well enough that you can visualize the page as you code it.